# Access to the path '(Temp Folder)' is denied. Happens when adding a project or class file to my Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am in need of some help.

I tried this on Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, and I am getting the same error.

I have a solution that I have been working on and I went to add a new class file to a project and I got the following error:

Access to the path "C:\Temp\yiswy0sj.5lo\Temp\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"

The previous error is slightly different, every time I try and create a new project, in the temp folder that it is creating. I went to the temp folder, and the assembly file is there, it is hidden and it has the correct assembly file info in it.

I am not able to add new projects or class files to any of my solutions.

I did quite a bit of research, and someone said to change the temp folder. I tried this as you can see the temp folder is not app data any more, it is Temp; and this did not solve the problem.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Any questions I will be more then happy to answer.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you are a local admin, what happens if you try to stat VS as an admin?

Comment: You could also attempt to set the temp folder to a folder in one of your user directories.

Comment: When this started, I was running under account JasonZ. He is a member of Administrators, Help Library Updaters, Home Users.

Comment: When I start Visual Studio as an administrator I get the same error when I try and add a new project or class file.

Comment: I created a new user JasonDev, he is a member of Administrators, HomeUsers, and Users. I get the same error.

Comment: As JasonDev user, the temp folder is set to "C:\Users\JasonDev\AppData\Local\Temp"

Answer (score 1):

I know how to fix the issue.   Under your program files (x86) flag all your Microsoft Visual Studio directories and files as NOT Hidden.  You have/had a virus that hid your files and this is causing the AssemblyInfo.cs in the temp folder to appear hidden as well.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I got rid of a virus this morning with system restore, and unhiding all the files fixed the problem. Only a few of the files were hidden, so I actually recursively hid the entire Visual Studio directory, and then recursively unhid everything.

Answer (score 0):

despite the error is in c:\ you have to unhide the visual studio directory which is my case is D:\Archivos de Programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0

the virus is check system, it simulate a hard disk fail, malwarebytes ged ride of it